# Google Maps API: pan to markers from a list.

Tags: javascript, list, maps, panning

Hello :) Please bear with me, I'm not a coder but I'm trying to learn by doing. This is the page I'm working on currently; http://www.websu.it/devnw/dev/contact.html.
I've currently set up a map using the Google Maps API, using the following javascript:

```
    function initialize() {

          var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 5,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.160, -6.832),
          disableDefaultUI: true,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };

         map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
             setMarkers(map, cities);
              }


 var cities = [
   ['Groningen', 53.216723950863425, 6.560211181640625, 4],
   ['San Francisco', 34.01131647557699, -118.25599389648437, 5],
   ['New York City', 40.7143528, -74.0059731, 3],
   ['Amsterdam', 52.3702157, 4.8951679, 2],
   ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
 ];

 function setMarkers(map, locations) {

   for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
     var city = locations[i];
     var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(city[1], city[2]);
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: myLatLng,
         map: map,
         title: city[0],
         zIndex: city[3]
     });
   }
 }

 This continues below...
```

And then I created a list where every li element, when clicked upon, results in a panning of the map to one of these markers.

I've added the following code and it works very well. But it means that I have to add the longitudes/latitudes for every city in the above code array of "cities", as well as in the code below for the var laLatLng. How can I get the lat's and lon's more easily in the panning script below?

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
      initialize();

      $("#contacts").on("click", "#sanfransisco", function() {
          var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.01131647557699, -118.25599389648437);
          map.panTo(laLatLng);
          map.setZoom(5);
       });
      $("#contacts").on("click", "#groningen", function() {
          var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.216723950863425, 6.560211181640625);
          map.panTo(laLatLng);
          map.setZoom(6);
      });
      $("#contacts").on("click", "#nyc", function() {
          var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.7143528, -74.0059731);
          map.panTo(laLatLng);
          map.setZoom(6);
      });
      $("#contacts").on("click", "#losangeles", function() {
          var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.3702157, 4.8951679);
          map.panTo(laLatLng);
          map.setZoom(6);
      });
  });
```

I hope someone can explain to me how to get the variables from cities into clickable list javascript. Thanks a lot, I deeply appreciate your response!

Comment: you want to fetch the lat/long of various cities based on the city name?

Comment: Yes, that would be ideal :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you convert the `cities` array to an object like:

```
var cities = {
  'Groningen':  [ 53.216723950863425, 6.560211181640625, 4],
   'San Francisco': [ 34.01131647557699, -118.25599389648437, 5],
   'New York City': [ 40.7143528, -74.0059731, 3]

};
```

And add a `data-` attribute with matching city name along with a common class name to each of the links:

```
/* not sure what html looks like , using pseudo "tagName"*/
<tagName class="map_link" data-city="Groningen">Groningen</tagName>
```

You can create one handler for the whole class:

```
$("#contacts").on("click", ".map_link", function() {
          /* "this" within handler is the actual element clciked*/

          /* find correct array from "cities" object */
         var data=cities[ $(this).data('city') ]; /* returns array[ 53.21, 6.56, 4]*/
          var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng( data[0],  data[1]);
          map.panTo(laLatLng);
          map.setZoom( data[2]);
       });
```

Comment: You are awesome! Going to try it. Thanks so much! Will come back here afterwards :)

Comment: This was indeed the best solution, thank you! Would you perhaps also know how to add a marker for each of these cities? I'm trying and can't get it to work, but perhaps I'll ask a new question on this site.

Comment: That one's here now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14308884/google-maps-api-v3-adding-markers-from-an-array-doesnt-work Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I'd do it, simply using the reverse geocoding capabilities of Google Maps to lookup the city names:

```
<ul id="cities">
  <li>San Fransisco</li>
  <li>Groningen</li>
  <li>New York City</li>
  <li>Los Angeles</li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$('#cities li').on('click', function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+decodeURIComponent( $(this).text() )+'&sensor=false',
    type: 'GET'
  }).done(function(data) {
    var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.results[0].geometry.location.lat, data.results[0].geometry.location.lng);
    map.panTo(laLatLng);
    map.setZoom(5);
  });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/Q9Vge/1/)

Comment: I thought of this but assumed OP may have specific lat/long within each city to focus on like a local office and also zoom is different for each city on OP array

Comment: Thank you adeneo for your help! I tried both your solution and the one of charlieftl, but as charlieftl stated, I needed to get the zoom-variable too. So I'll go with that one :) Thanks!