# Google Maps API v3: Adding markers from an array doesn't work

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

first of all thanks for considering to answer this :) Much appreciated!

I've created a map using the following code, and this works perfectly.

```
    function initialize() {

          var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 5,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.160, -6.832),
          disableDefaultUI: true,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };

           map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
  setMarkers(map, cities);
 }
```

But then I want markers at each of the cities in this array (please don't suggest changing this as this exact piece of code solves another problem I had, unless of course absolutely neccesary):

```
 var cities = {
   'Groningen':  [ 53.216723950863425, 6.560211181640625, 7],
    'San Francisco': [ 34.01131647557699, -118.25599389648437, 5],
    'New York City': [ 40.7143528, -74.0059731, 3]

 };
```

And I'm using this code to place the actual markers (which is the part that doesn't work):

```
  function setMarkers(map, locations) {
   // Add markers to the map

  for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
          var data = cities [i]
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: new google.maps.LatLng (data[0], data[1]),
              map: map,
              icon: image,
              title: 'test',
          });
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cities` isn't an array but an object so you can't use

```
for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
    //...
}
```

Use this instead

```
for (var key in cities) {
    var data = cities[key];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng (data[0], data[1]),
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title: 'test',
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for answering! Unfortunately it still doesn't place a marker. You can see the whole map at http://www.websu.it/devnw/dev/contact.html The latitude and longitude should be a place in The Netherlands and it does not show up :( Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Haha looking at that console all the time; and just now I forgot. Thanks. sorry haha.